# Bing Image match API

Tags: image-processing, bing, bing-api

I'm looking at the Bing developer search API, trying to find information about Image match search, where an image is the search parameter, just as running bing in explorer. So far I can only find search using string parameters and not image to find matches. Can someone guide me in a direction or is this not available in the api ?

best regards

Comment: could you solve it? I face with similar challenge: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31515752/how-to-send-http-to-bing-image-search-api

Comment: @János I haven't found a solutino to search by image. I saw your post, but as far as I understand you search for images using a term correct?