# How-to send HTTP message to Bing Image Search API?

Tags: bing-api

Try to use Bing Image Search API, like how-to explained [here](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=9C9479871FBFA822!112&app=Word&authkey=!ANNnJQREB0kDC04). But I get an error.

`Parameter: Query is not of type String` Any idea?

**howto**:

[image]

**me**: (in the popup both for `username` and `password` I set the `Primary Account Key`) Tried without `%27`, ay you see I did not set any header field, hopefully it is not problem.

[image]

Comment: I've been omitting the username and just putting in the password and it works so maybe try that... the Query itself looks totally fine...

Comment: hey, I set only password, but not operational, same error

Comment: I guess I found here the solution, instead of `%27`, `'` character need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080298/azure-bing-web-search-fails-with-query-search